# Ubuntu 12.04 Volume up down mute stopped working

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, volume-control

I'm using a Lenovo SL500 for several years now and suddenly the Volume keys
stopped working. It could be that a kernel updated caused it - I don't know.

However when I go to the keyboard settings -> Shortcuts -> Sound and Media, I can set e.g. Volume Mute with my multimedia key and then it says "AudioMute". But when I later hit the Volume Mute key nothing happens.

Comment: Maybe your volume/mute keys got reassigned to some other program?

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys

Comment: I tried a new user account and there everything was ok. So it's definitely a settings problem. However `xmodmap -pke` gives the same output in both user accounts.

Comment: It's a bug, see here................ https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1248368

Comment: There is another one here too.. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1302885

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution: deleting `~/.pulse` then logout. Next time it happens I will try the other answer too.

Comment: This has fixed my problem, but you must reboot the computer, not just logout, or you may find all the sound controls to be quite broken. I recommending taking a backup of .pulse incase you need to revert.

Comment: This is the right answer, helped me too.

Comment: Deleted folder and rebooted. This helped in my case as well (Asus N55S). It restored the sound previously gone from the left headphone channel and the volume and mute keys. Thanks!

Comment: I just killed pulse-audio instead of logging out, it worked

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on 15.04

There was no `.pulse` but there was `.pulse-cookie`. So I deleted it and it works like a charm now.

So updated solution for 15.04:

```
sudo rm ~/.pulse-cookie
```

Comment: This also works on ubuntu 12.04. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Resetting media key prefrences worked for me

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/settings- daemon/plugins/media-keys/
```

if it does not work maybe you should try

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/settings- daemon/plugins
```